# in r, can I see if a numeric variable has values like a factor?

Tags: r

I have a variable (in a column) and I know I can check whether it is numeric or not using class and it is numeric, it has values such as 3 and 4 and would like to check if these numbers have a meaning? i.e. does 3 mean good and 4 mean bad.

I have tried using `attributes(df$variableIwantToSee)$labels` and get NULL.

Basically, can I check what the value of a numeric variable are in a similar way to attributes( )$labels?

Comment: `class(df$variableIwantToSee)` will tell you if it is a factor. `str(df$variableIwantToSee)` will tell you if it is a factor and what the first few levels are. If it is a factor, `levels(df$variableIwantToSee)` will tell you what the factor levels are.

Comment: Where is your data coming from?  It sounds like you are talking about labelled variables which are not a base class (e.g. created by the `haven` or `labelled` packages).

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I am using the haven package/library and it is an imported data set and want to see if these values have labels

Comment: @dcarlson my variable of interes `class(df$variableIwantToSee)` is numeric and want to see if this variable has labels attached

Comment: @ineedhelp - that is some pretty important context to leave out.  You can use the `is.labelled()` function to test if your variables have labels.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento good catch and thank you! that is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @RitchieSacramento so if the variable would appear as true for `is.labelled()`, I would then use `attributes()$labels` to check for the labels, right?

Comment: You can use the convenience function `val_labels()`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento, thanks again for your help! I installed the labelled library and was able to get `val_labels()` to work